# The bar changes color

Tags: android, colors, android-gridlayout

Some info about the app

```
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout;
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 28
```

In my Android app I have this problem, just began using the `GridLayout`.
I need to know how to fix it.

When the app starts, the color bar is black.
[image]

If I change the tiles color, the bar changes color.
[image]

If the original tiles color come back, again the bar changes color.
[image]

Comment: So you want to keep it as black?

Comment: Yes, always black.

Comment: Check if your activity is in full screen mode or not

Comment: It is not because I need the bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#000000")));
```

I think this might help you. I use it to change the colour of the bar

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `android:windowTranslucentStatus` to `false`

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
```